# Redirect 4 different URLs to a single URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a query that I'm hoping a URL rewriting wizard can help me with as this one is a little beyond me.

I have the following URLs:

http://www.domain.com/region/news/123456-article-name-goes-here.html
http://www.domain.com/region/news/123456-article-name-goes-here.html?get_var=1234
http://www.domain.com/mobile/region/news/123456-article-name-goes-here.html
http://www.domain.com/mobile/region/news/123456-article-name-goes-here.html?get_var=1234

I need to redirect all of these variations to a URL in the following format:

http://www.domain.com/region/article-name-goes-here/

So I need to remove 'mobile/', remove 'news/', remove '123456-', remove .html, remove any GET variables, and then add a trailing slash.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is what you need:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/region/news/\d+-(.+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/region/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/mobile/region/news/\d+-(.+)\.html$  http://www.domain.com/region/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

You could do that with one rule, but the above is easier to understand, so I'd use two rules.

---

Note: this is the version for the host configuration. If you need to use `.htaccess` style files instead, then you have to remove the leading slashes from the patterns in the rules, since those files work on *relative* paths. Note however that whenever possible you should prefer the host configuration variant over `htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, cumbersome to implement, harder to debug and *really* slow the server down. So only rely on them if you *really* have to, for example if you do not have access to the host configuration.

Comment: @PanamaJack That is possible, indeed. However I consider it bad style. It makes things more complex and confusing without offering a benefit for a specific application. If you implement such rules then you know where you place them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one single rule to redirect those urls :

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(?:mobile/)?/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ http://example.com/$1/$4/? [NC,L,R]
```

? is important at the end of the rule,as it discards the orignal querystrings from url